# ClassCastException with EhCache 2.6.0

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm using EhCache to store a limited size cache of my application objects but after upgrading its version I'm getting this exception when using *cache.get(...)*:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap$DummyPinnedKey cannot be cast to br.com.project.util.VttcElement
```

Does anybody know if is there any new interface we should implement in our cached keys?

Here's my adapted code:

```
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;

private VttcElementCache() {
    CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create(METAINFFileLoader.getInputStream("ehcache.xml"));
    cache = cacheManager.getCache("br.com.project.util.VttcElement");
}

private void load(int id, long idf) {
    cache.put(new Element(new VttcElement(id, idf), "1"));
}

private String get(VttcElement vttcElement) {
    Element element = cache.get(vttcElement); //The exception is thrown here!
    (String) return elemente.getValue();
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Comment: Sorry but I had to edit with the real exception thrown point. It's on the _cache.get_.

Comment: There is nothing you should implement there, but there is a bug one of releases. I would need to double check... but the exception you are seeing is related to pinning. Which you don't seem to do... 
Are you using Hibernate with the same cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

For some reason my key class *VttcElement* was not been well stored inside the cache because the exception was thrown inside its *equals* method right in the line it makes *(VttcElement) obj*.

I changed all my keys to Strings instead *VttcElement* using its attributes concatenated with comma and it worked as key perfectly.

Thanks a lot.